# form not auto submitting

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am using google maps api to get user location. It returns data in js variable. Now I want to convert this js variable into php. I have used form submission to convert variable but the issue is that the form is not auto submitting.

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['loc'])){
            ?>
        <script>alert("i am post!");
        </script>
    <?php
            echo "i am post";
            $country_name = $_POST['abc'];
            echo $country_name."i am php";
        }
        else{
            echo "i am php else";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var country_name;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
        }
        //Get the latitude and the longitude;
        function successFunction(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            codeLatLng(lat, lng)
        }

        function errorFunction() {
            alert("Geocoder failed");
        }

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



        }

        function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    //console.log(results)
                    if (results[1]) {
                        //formatted address
                       // alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                        //find country name
                        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                            for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {

                                //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
                                    //this is the object you are looking for
                                    city = results[0].address_components[i];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //city data
                        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)
                        country_name = city.short_name;
                        document.forms[0].abc.value = country_name;
                        $("#def").submit();
                        document.write("form is submited");

                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script> 

    <body onload="initialize()"> 
        <form id="def" action="Db1.php" method="POST">
            <input name="abc" id="abc" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="loc" />
        </form>
    </body> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            alert(" i am jquery function");
            window.onload(function () {
                $("#def").submit();
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php 

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: what the hell -2 and no response :(

Comment: you have forgot to include `jquery`.. please include it before including the google maps js

Comment: `$(function()` fails without jquery. :P

Comment: i have included jquery.

Comment: Have you watched to see if there is a request / response in your browser's console?

Comment: Now i have included this link too <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> but its still not working :(

Comment: The google maps api is working. The alert of location is shown but form is not auto submitting.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? You may be submitting, but the input (`id=abc`) has *no* value. If it is submitting it isn't sending anything.

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Id=abc has value it is shown in input field. I am from Pakistan so PK is shown in input field.

Comment: OK. Have you removed the alert and watched the console?

Answer (score -1):

replace your script

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            alert(" i am jquery function");
            window.onload(function () {
                $("#def").submit();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

with this

```
     <script>
                document.getElementById('def').submit();
     </script>
```

**EDIT**
if you want to submit using jquery than do this

```
$( "#def" )[0].submit();
```

Comment: downvote without any reason?? I tried this code and it is working.... with the whole OP script

Comment: I didn't DV, but I can see why it was. Testing with the jQuery function (I exchanged the `alert()` for a `console.log()`) and making sure the input had a value there were no issues with the submission.

Comment: yep.. may be the issue is she is using two nested auto load functions together `$(function() { and window.onload(function() {`....

Comment: @Nishant_Solanki thanks for answer but its not working. Actually the script code after body tag is not executing. "i am jquery function " alert does not appear.

Comment: @Ayesha just use only  `$( "#def" )[0].submit(); `... remove other codes from your last script....